# SSHFS - serving remote dev code to my local browser, connecting to data behind a VPN

Tags: vpn, vps, sshfs

Apologies if this isn't the correct forum for this question.

I'm toying with the idea of putting some of my dev code on a VPS, so I can access it easily from different places, and push some of the processing responsibilities off my somewhat underpowered laptop. I'm concerned on whether it will work with my setup:

- Dev code would be on the VPS, mounted locally via SSHFS
- I'd access the compiled dev code via my local browser
- The app gets its data served through a VPN connection to my employer's server.

So, if my *local* machine is connected to the VPN, is that enough? Or would the VPS *also* need a VPN connection?

Sorry if that doesn't make sense - I can try and clarify if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the VPN configuration. Most small to medium corporate VPNs are set so that clients can access company resources from outside, which could make your server a client. Client to client communication may be blocked.

It is also possible that the VPN is somewhat simpler and would just give you access the the company local network. In that case you might be able to access the server the same way as your employer, via SSHFS or HTTP.

If it is you who is setting up the VPN, you'll need to make sure it allows all the required traffic. If that's your employer's vpn, I suggest you to explain to them what you need and let them configure their VPN to allow it to work.